# Edit image src with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have one question I'm using this code for editing image src's thats creating js but its not working ...(after click on button jquery creating object and then this function will change src's in this created object )

that code where first creating objects and second will edit image src's

```
function addToplaylist(title)
    {
       /* some CODE */

                var each = playlistts.join('</span><li><img class="plimg" src="/img/cover.png"><span  onclick="playinToplaylist($(this).html());" class="titletrack">');
                 $("#playlist").html('<li><img onload="this.src = \'/img/playlist/\'+$(this).next(\'span.titletrack\').text()+\'.jpg\'" src="/img/cover.png"><span  onclick="playinToplaylist($(this).html());" class="titletrack">' + each);

/* some CODE */

    }


    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("body .plimg").attr("src",

        function (index) {
    var title = $(this).next('span.titletrack').text();
            var array = title.split(' - ');
            var track = array[0];
            var artist = array[1];

            var output;

            $.ajax({ //instead of getJSON as the function does not allow configurations.
                url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search",
                data: {
                    track: track,
                    artist: artist,
                    api_key: "ca86a16ce762065a423e20381ccfcdf0",
                    format: "json",
                    lang: "en",
                    limit: 1
                },
                async: false, //making the call synchronous
                dataType: 'json', //specifying JSON type
                success: function (data) {
                    output = data.results.trackmatches.track.image[0]["#text"];
                }

            });
            return output;
        });
    });
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SwUrn/

Comment: with inner html thats my code works too but when when html creating js its not working

Comment: Can you tell us what `playlistts` is, and why you're using a `join`? The issue likely comes from the way the HTML is generated from your JS code.

Comment: its cookie where comma seperated names of tracks, playlist is cookie where comma seperated youtube ids... i dont know how to make nicer  code and becouse using it..